# Iterate over groups in pandas to extract a top

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Client': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
               'Project': ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P2', 'P3', 'P1', 'P2', 'P4'],
               'Freq': [5, 2, 3, 4, 6, 9, 7, 2, 4]})

  Client Project  Freq
0      A      P1     5
1      A      P2     2
2      A      P3     3
3      A      P4     4
4      B      P2     6
5      B      P3     9
6      B      P1     7
7      C      P2     2
8      C      P4     4
```

and I want to achieve this one:

```
  Client Project Top 1 Project Top 2 Project Top 3
0      A            P1            P4            P3
1      B            P3            P1            P2
2      C            P4            P2             -
```

but I have not idea how operate and extract each top project over the groups.

I hope you can help me, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Groupby First - Extract Index from Original Dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61021026/pandas-groupby-first-extract-index-from-original-dataframe)

Comment: It works for me but it doesn't solve the problem of getting the second and the third project, which is the step that is causing me the most problems. Anyway thanks for that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) by both columns, by `Freq` descending. Then create counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), filter by top values and reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
N = 3 
df = df.sort_values(['Client','Freq'], ascending=[True, False])
g = df.groupby('Client').cumcount().add(1)
mask = g <= N
df = (df[mask].set_index(['Client',g[mask]])['Project']
              .unstack()
              .add_prefix('Project Top ')
              .reset_index())
print (df)
  Client Project Top 1 Project Top 2 Project Top 3
0      A            P1            P4            P3
1      B            P3            P1            P2
2      C            P4            P2           NaN
```

Comment: nice mask, imagine that OP wanted to subtract a limited number of groups. Congratulations almost 500k! :)